# How to say something is the only way

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know the ways to say something is the only way

Are these correct?

> There is no way than to go to a safe place
>
> There is no way except to go to a safe place
>
> You left me no way than telling this to John
>
> We can't do much except to wait
>
> We can't do anything other than to fight
>
> We can do nothing but to fight

Comment: I believe that these are more idiomatic: 1) *There is no other way than going to a safe place.* 2) *There isn't any (other) way except {by going|(to) go} to a safe place.* 3) *You left me no choice but to tell {John this|this to John}.* They are not exhaustive though, and your examples are too marginal for me to judge reliably whether they're incorrect or not. FWIW, I think only #2 is probably okay.

Comment: @DamkerngT. thank you, your #3 was almost new and useful to me, meanwhile I added some other sentences to the list to make it complete

Comment: To 3) I'd probably add "other": *You left me no **other** choice than...*, and the last for some reason sounds better to me without the 'to': *We can do nothing but fight.*

Comment: There is not any other option except ... X is our only option

Answer (score 2):

> There is no way than to go to a safe place

I would say "There is no other way than to go to a safe place," or "There is no way other than to go to a safe place." I think this is idiomatic here, as using "There is no" + "than" requires the word "other" either before "than" or "way".

> There is no way except to go to a safe place

Sounds good.

> You left me no way than telling this to John

Same issue as first sentence. "You left me no other way than..." or "You left me no way other than..."

> We can't do much except to wait

I would say "We can't do much except wait." I don't have grammar research to support this, but I believe it is related to answering a question with the use of the modal + do. It is similar to "What can we do? [We can] wait." but **not** "What can we do? [We can] to wait. We are omitting a complete sentence but keeping the grammatical form intact. Introducing the infinitive makes the sentence ungrammatical so we won't say it like that.

> We can't do anything other than to fight

Same issue as the sentence before. I would say "We can't do anything other than fight."

> We can do nothing but to fight

Same issue. I would say "We can do nothing but fight."

Comment: Thank you, just if there are other ways except (except, other than, but) to say such sentences please let me know.

Comment: I can't think of any at the moment. I think if you use "except, other than, but", then there is no other way except to succeed :)